# Tab Bar Controller is not in all UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I just created a tab bar controller in my project with 4 tabs in total.

It works fine between the 4 UIViewControllers.

However when I navigate to another UIViewController which is not one of the 4 tabs, the tab bar disappears.

I want it to be seen in every page. How can I do this?

Comment: How are you navigating to the other view controller?

Comment: with buttons that are push segues or performseguewithidentifier. For example in facebook there are again 4 tabs, but when you click to a profile name and navigate to the profile page of any user, the tab bar remains still there.

Comment: Ok. Added and answer. It should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

The way this is done is by using navigation controllers on each tab.

So, you have your tab bar controller. Then each tab has a navigation controller first and the root view controller of the navigation controller is the page you want in that tab.

Now when you use a push segue the navigation controller pushes the new page and the tab bar controller remains in place.