# how to display Tab Bar Controller in all UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tabs

My iPhone app display Tab-bar with 3 tabs on button Click.
It works fine with initial 3 UIViewControllers.
But when I try to push new UIViewController within any TAB, tab bar disappears.
I even tried other solution mention here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087181/tab-bar-controller-is-not-in-all-uiviewcontrollers](http://Solution)
However I could only see blank space with no tab bar options...

[image]

I tried without navigation pushing UIViewController like normal way. I
also pushing `UIViewController` from Tab bar (having navigation controller for `UIViewController`) but any of ways not giving me desired result.
I do not want two navigation item or pushing new view without tab bar.

All UIViewController's should display within one navigation and Tab bar.

Please help

NOTE: i load TABBar from click of button on home uiviewcontroller like

like

```
    -(IBAction)btnReceivePressed:(id)sender
 {
     TabBarViewController *about_vc = (TabBarViewController*)[[UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TABBAR"];
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:about_vc animated:YES];
 }
```

below are the screen shot which shows two navigation item ..
    [image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrETS.png)
    [[image]][4
    [image]

Comment: If you push, the tabbar should persist unless you checked the `hides bottom bar on push` option for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to set property of UIViewcontroller:

[image]

**Another solution** for Two Navigation Bar :

You need to change in AppDelgate as below :

From :

```
 UINavigationController *naController =[[UINavigationController alloc ]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
  naController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
  self.window.rootViewController = naController;
```

With :

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

**Third Solution** If you are using push .

```
- (IBAction)btnReceivePressed:(id)sender {
    TabBarViewController about_vc = (TabBarViewController)
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TABBAR"]; 
    [self navigationController].navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:about_vc animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: no use , navigation bar title comes below ..like two navigation item will post screen shorts...

Comment: attach screenshot in question .

Comment: this is occur due to your tabViewcontroller's navigationcontroller . please remove it .

Comment: i do not have navigation controller for TABbar.... on click of button from home uiviewcontroller i load tabbarcontroller

Comment: - (IBAction)btnReceivePressed:(id)sender
 {
     TabBarViewController *about_vc = (TabBarViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TABBAR"];
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:about_vc animated:YES];
 }

Comment: but this approach not correct . tabbarcontroller should be rootViewContrller of NavigationController .

Comment: Use this  instead of push : self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Comment: if you use push then you need to remove navigation controller which are attached with tab bar . you need to use only one navigationcontroller.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer....just 1 Question please my TABBAr always open with 1st TAB...i wanted it should open with any TAB..... i am using TABBAR in storyboard...

Comment: my TABBAr always open with 1st TAB...i wanted it should open with any TAB..... i am using TABBAR in storyboard

Comment: try this :     about_vc.selectedIndex = 2 ;  // you can set index as per your require.